# Python SyntaxError with a correct syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

Why this code gives me a syntax error:

```
eval(1485*'not ' + '1')
```

Obviously the syntax is correct. Below 1485 works fine. And with 1496 and above I get a memory error. I think it should rise a MemoryError instead of SyntaxError.

Comment: `eval("1485*'not ' + '1'")` runs fine on my machine, but I guess I should ask: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Rafael is right, eval function takes a string argument.

Comment: *why* are you doing this?

Comment: @RafaelBarros thats because in your case it just returns a string. Note there are no double quotes around.

Comment: @RafaelBarros and user1269942, he's generating a string with 14895 "not"s in front of a '1', then evaling it.  It's valid as written, just... nonsensical.

Comment: Its just a plain curiosity. But in my opinion should not raise a syntax error.

Comment: Look at the first line of output in the traceback.  The cause is clearly stated: `s_push: parser stack overflow`.  It looks like you overwhelmed the parser (at least, that is the result on my Windows 7 machine running Python 2.7.8).

Comment: @SilasRay: you're right. maybe it needs to be a literal and not a returned string?

Comment: You're probably hitting an edge case of the interpreter.  My first guess would be that 1496+ nots produces an out of memory error during string construction while between 1485 and 1496 results in some error in eval resulting from trying to eval a string buffer that is too large for it to handle (thus a syntax error).  It's kind of more work than it is worth to track down the exact answer though.  Or as @iCodez pointed out as I typed this, the stack trace tells you...

Comment: @iCodez I am getting 's_push: parser stack overflow' with 1496 or more. With 1485 just a syntax error. I am only wondering if somebody can explain why the error type depends on the value of that numer.

Comment: @SilasRay actually, there is a difference. having the way the asker has it is equivalent to typing  notnotnot1 in a python window, that's the error.  but having it enclosed in a string just constructs a string.

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski ok, what's happening is the following, you multiply the 'not' by 1485, but that generates a string that is evaluated and becomes 1485 `not` statements (the key word) in a row, and then the number `1`.

Comment: @user1269942, wrong, he has a trailing space after the "not".

Comment: again: `eval(1486*'"not "' + '"1"')` runs on my machine just fine.

Comment: @SilasRay probably you are right. I thought there is a simple answer to this one. It is not worth checking

Comment: @RafaelBarros That just evals as a really long string, not the same thing.

Comment: @SilasRay  my bad, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parser has limits, and you are hitting them. See http://bugs.python.org/issue1881 for a discussion, but you managed to add enough `not` operators in there to run out of parser stack space.

You can hit the same limit by nesting lists, see http://bugs.python.org/issue215555:

```
>>> eval(100 * '[' + 100 * ']')
s_push: parser stack overflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Quoting that latter report:

> There is a limit that is based on the C stack, because the parser is recursive descent.

Providing code that hits that limit is considered a syntax error too; e.g. 1485 `not` operators in a row is insane and cannot possibly be considered valid Python. :-)

The reason you are getting a EOF error rather than a MemoryError for certain lengths is simply that the tokenizer manages to get to the end of the line (and signals an EOF) for those lengths, and *then* the parser stack overflows, rather than that the parser stack overflowed before the tokenizer had seen the end of the line.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't explain why it's `SyntaxError` for the values from 1485 to 1496, and `MemoryError` otherwise.

Comment: @georg: the memory error is hit in the parser too, again due to running out of stack space, but more so.

Comment: @georg: dug a little more; the parser stack overflow is always a MemoryError, but if the tokenizer has seen the end of the line already as it feeds tokens to the parser, the memory error is replaced by the syntax error.